# Enable/Disable Google Cloud Datastore writes through gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

According to my research, there is no way to run a gcloud command to disable/enable datastore writes of a standard AppEngine project. Can anyone confirm ?
Any idea if this is something that will never be available because its relative to a low end datastore administration or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation matches mine. The only documented method of disabling datastore writes is via the Datastore Admin page. From [Enabling or disabling Cloud Datastore writes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/console/managing-datastore#enabling_datastore_writes):

> To enable or disable Cloud Datastore writes:
>
> - Go to the **Admin** page.
>
> [GO TO THE ADMIN PAGE](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/settings)
>
> - Click **Enable writes** to enable writes, or **Disable writes** to disable writes. The button text varies, depending on the state of your
>     project.

But note that it isn't entirely effective:

> **Note**: The Cloud Datastore API does not allow forcing writes when writes are disabled. However, App Engine client libraries allow
>   forcing writes even if writes are disabled. So an application written
>   with the App Engine client libraries could modify your Cloud Datastore
>   instance while writes are disabled.

I see no mentioning of such capability in either of:

- the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) reference
- the Datastore [REST](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/)/[RPC](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/) APIs
- the Datastore Admin [REST](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/)/[RPC](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rpc/) APIs
- the App Engine Admin [REST](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/)/[RPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rpc/) APIs

I can't really comment on the future plans, but nothing stops you from filing a feature request at the Cloud SDK [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/187143/manage#basic). With the importance of automation in sw development I wouldn't think it'd be unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Alongside the write disabler of the datastore administration dashboard I just created a read / write flag on a wrapper I wrote around datastore's ndb entities management for my application. So doing the trick so far.

Comment: That works, too, if you have such wrapper. Great idea - I have a wrapper I used for other stuff, now I know what else I can do with it :)